# Expressions and str_replace

Tags: customization

```
<div class="form-container">

    <div class="form-field">
        <label>
            <input id="woo-bookings-enabled" type="checkbox" name="woo-bookings-enabled" value="1">Enable bookings
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field hide-if-bookings-disabled" style="display: block;">
        <label>
            Length:  <input type="number" name="..." value="1">
            <select>
                    <option>...</option>
                    <option>...</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>


    <div class="form-field hide-if-bookings-disabled">
        <label>Cost: <input type="number" name="session-cost" value="0" min="0" step="0.01">
        </label>
    </div>


    <div class="form-field hide-if-bookings-disabled">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="customer-timezone" value="on">Use the customer's timezone
        </label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now I'd like to add an extra html code `<span class="form-field-checkbox"></span>` to `input["type=checkbox"]` only.

My function is like this but it doesn't work as I hoped it would.

```
function theme_form_checkbox($output) {
    $search  = array('<div class="form-field"><label><input .*?checkbox.*?>','</label>');
    $replace = array('<div class="form-field"><label><input .*?checkbox.*?>', '<span class="form-field-checkbox"></span></label>'); 

    return str_replace( $search, $replace, $output );
}   
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_form_checkbox', 99, 1 );
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` in case you want to use regular expressions.

Comment: Could you give an example? I have some dificulties with the expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at this from a far difficult angle, while the answer was so simple. For anyone in a similar situation:

```
$('<span class="form-field-checkbox"></span>').insertAfter('input:checkbox,input:radio');
```